# Server for saving TCP packets from routers

Tags: python, logging, server, network-programming

Asking for advice here.

So I have a business that sells a specific kind of routers. One of the features is to monitor the activity of the router (i.e. making sure it's "live"). I asked the manufacturer of the routers to program them to send a TCP "ping" packet to my server IP address, to a specific port, every 15 minutes, with very basic data for monitoring (router serial number, "I'm alive" string).
I have a Windows Server running on a static IP which receives the data.

I tested this by sending a packet using `netcat`, and I can see it's received correctly. I used freeware called [Packet Sender](https://packetsender.com/) to open a specific TCP port and log the incoming traffic.

What I need to do now is run code on my server which listens to the specific port, and saves the data (router serial number, time of transmission, etc.) in a DB. This way, customers will later be able to log into their account, and view their router's "activity". There will also be advanced features like notifying the customer whenever the server doesn't receive data from their router over a period of X minutes/hours, etc.

I'm asking for advice as to how to set this up in the best way. I read about simple Python code that can listen to a port (like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47316167/2996797)), and I guess I can use that to save the data to a local DB.
But would that be best? What about race conditions (i.e. multiple routers sending data at the same time)? I guess these transmissions wuould need to enter into some basic queue and be dealt with one by one? Is there some good exiting framework I can use that will do all this for me?

Any advice as to how to implement this would be great. I know some basic Python backend programming.

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? There already exist multiple solutions that do this. You should really use a standard, tested solution that can be used by multiple vendor products.

Comment: @RonMaupin Firstly, I don't know of existing solutions - if you know of anything specific that is suitable for my specific needs - please let me know. Secondly, doing it myself allows me great flexibility which I'll probably need.

Comment: Various things like SNMP, NetFlow, and especially IP SLA. Network device monitoring has been around for decades, and there are many solutions that offer various features. For example, IP SLA can test many aspects of networking, including network performance like latency, ping response, jitter, VoIP, etc. There are applications that can use one or more of the various protocols to track and report. As a network engineer, I want to use something that works with all my network devices, not a custom application for a single network device.

Comment: Thanks, I looked some of these up. However, I'm looking for a very "tailored solution" for very specific needs, and I don't need any advanced monitoring. I just need to build something simple that will receive the "pings" and store in DB. This is also a project I want to develop myself for other reasons, and I'm looking for programming advice, not software solutions.

Comment: Not to sound harsh, but you should really ask yourself if you are unfamiliar with such standard network protocols, should you really be doing network programming? "_I just need to build something simple that will receive the "pings" and store in DB._" You can do that using the standard network protocols. You can, for example, have IP SLA only do ping. I have no problem with you experimenting, but you should not try to foist this off on customers as the solution for this router you sell.

Comment: There are [dozens of applications that do network monitoring and alerting](https://www.gartner.com/reviews/market/network-performance-monitoring) using the standard, built-in protocols, and a company is going to choose one to use for the entire organization, not using a one-off, custom solution for a router you sell. I want to monitor all my routers, switches, servers, etc. from a single application, not an application for each vendor.

Comment: Thanks, I hear your advice. I'll definitely take it into account. I am still interested in the programming part of this question.

Comment: That is fine, but you should use one of the standard, built-in protocols to monitor the device with the application you build. It would be a good learning experience to see how to monitor devices using one or more of the standard protocols designed for that.

Comment: Got you, will look into the protocols you sent, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood your question, but it seems as simple as just using a module like `socket` [HERE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) and either a simple `csv` file or maybe even a `pandas` [HERE](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/index.html) database. 

I do think you are on the right page with using python, but if there are too many clients you may want to switch over to something lower level or simply faster like `rust` or `go`.

As for the race condition concern; you could use a module like `threading` or simply making your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Correct answer with TCP

You can basically use https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example to accept tcp pings and write it to a database.

Demo database using the standard library sqllite3  https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Demo server using standard library Httpserver https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/http.server.html#module-http.server to do some basic fetching

```py
import socketserver
import time
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from threading import Thread
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("test.db", check_same_thread = False)
cur = con.cursor()
try:
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE TCPPING(time, port, data)")
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    print("Table is already made")


def parse_and_add_to_db(line: str, port):
    cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO TCPPING VALUES('{time.time()}', {port}, '{line}')")

def tcp_reciever_thread():
    class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
        def handle(self):
            data = self.request.recv(1024).decode("latin-1")
            parse_and_add_to_db(data, self.client_address[1])
            self.request.sendall(b"ADDED")

    class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
        pass

    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 6000

    ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler).serve_forever()

    
tcp_reciever = Thread(target=tcp_reciever_thread)
tcp_reciever.daemon = True
tcp_reciever.start()

#Server
class functionserver(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        a, b = self.path[1:].split("/")
        print(a, b)
        data = cur.execute(f"SELECT * from TCPPING where {a}=='{b}'").fetchall()
        #OUTPUT
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write((("\n".join(map(str,data))).encode()))
        self.wfile.flush()
        
    def log_message(args,*kwargs):
        return None
        
httpd = HTTPServer(("127.0.0.1", 5000), functionserver)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

#### client.py

```py
import socket

ip = "localhost"
port = 6000

def client(message):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        sock.connect((ip, port))
        sock.sendall(message.encode())
        response = str(sock.recv(1024), 'ascii')
        print("Received: {}".format(response))

client("abc")
```

## Wrong older answer where I thought it was ICMP ping and used tcp dump to capture

1. icmp packets do not really have a "port" for listening to. I would suggest using tcpdump to capture this data. If possible you should use standard post requests to get the data.
2. Maxmillion's answer is basically how to scale up an app for enterprise, not how to make it. For accomplishing the basic requirements on local, we only need the standard library and tcpdump.

Overview

1. We have a database using sqllite3 https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html
2. We have a daemon thread that uses subprocess.Popen https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html to get tcpdump https://www.tcpdump.org/ output, parse it and write it to the database
3. In the main thread we start a Httpserver https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/http.server.html#module-http.server to do some basic fetching

```py
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from threading import Thread
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("test.db", check_same_thread = False)
cur = con.cursor()
try:
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE PINGS(time, ip1, ip2, type, id, seq, length)")
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    print("Table is already made")


def parse_and_add_to_db(line: str):
    line = line.replace(",", "")
    time, _1, ip1, _2, ip2, _3, _4, type, _5, id, _6, seq, _7, length  = line.split()
    ip2 = ip2[:-1]
    # print(f"inserting ('{time}', '{ip1}', '{ip2}', '{type}', {id}, {seq}, {length})")
    cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO PINGS VALUES('{time}', '{ip1}', '{ip2}', '{type}', {id}, {seq}, {length})")

def tcpdump_thread():
    # proc = Popen("sudo tcpdump -l -w /dev/null -i utun3 icmp --print -f -xx".split(), stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) # if we want the packet hex
    proc = Popen("sudo tcpdump -l -w /dev/null -i YOURINTERFACE icmp --print -f".split(), stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) # start a process to moitor pings
    assert proc.stdin is not None and proc.stdout is not None and proc.stderr is not None
    proc.stdin.write("YOURPASSWORDHERE\n".encode()) # password
    proc.stdin.flush()
    print("START")
    while True:
        parse_and_add_to_db(proc.stdout.readline().decode("latin-1"))

bg_tcpdump = Thread(target=tcpdump_thread)
bg_tcpdump.daemon = True
bg_tcpdump.start()

#Server
class functionserver(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        a, b = self.path[1:].split("/")
        print(a, b)
        data = cur.execute(f"SELECT * from PINGS where {a}=='{b}'").fetchall()
        #OUTPUT
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write((("\n".join(map(str,data))).encode()))
        self.wfile.flush()
        
    def log_message(args,*kwargs):
        return None
        
httpd = HTTPServer(("127.0.0.1", 5000), functionserver)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

You can run this (tcpdump needs sudo and you need to put the correct interface to listen to pings on so you need to configure those) and access `localhost:5000/ip1/1.1.1.1` in your browser and run `ping 1.1.1.1` in the background and see the database entries pop up.

If you want to do some parsing with the packet hex data you can use the line with `# if we want the packet hex`
and you can uncomment the print statement in parse to debug.

Hope this helps.

Additional

1. this is a very crude demo code
2. do not directly put strings into sql for queries
3. and possibly have a
   different process (instead of running the tcpdump and parsing in the server process)
4. Even if you scale up using a proper database and fastapi/flask/django and sqlAlchemy for the server instead of this, the logic should be similar.

For the suggested best practices -

1. If you do not have a database, choose one on the cloud which will have an api.
2. You don't need to bother about race conditions when using a production quality database. And tcp dump should have no issues keeping up with multiple pings.
3. For alerts you could query the db at regular intervals (polling) for certain conditions from your webapp.
4. For dumping the ping data you just need to dump it from your ping monitoring app.
5. Overall it is not an overly difficult system to design and does not need advanced networking knowledge to create an unoptimized version which works reliably.
6. Using c/c++/rust or other low level languages to get into the kernel/driver/network stack will give much better performance. But this is a python question.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Just one question - why use `tcpdump` instead of a Python/NodeJS server that listens to the specific port using a socket library and parsing whatever comes in?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, and according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol - `There is no TCP or UDP port number associated with ICMP packets as these numbers are associated with the transport layer above.` and `ICMP is a network-layer protocol, this makes it layer 3 protocol by the 7 layer OSI model.`. I don't think there's a way for a normal application/socket to capture it as it is handled by the kernel. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439801/what-linux-process-is-responsible-for-responding-to-pings

Comment: There's some misunderstanding here - I already tested by using the simple server code I mentioned in my question, and it works...

Comment: looks like I misread the tcp ping in the question as icmp ping.

Comment: You could probably use something like https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example instead of tcpdump. I'll update the answer with the fix in some time.

Answer (score -5):

Here's a quick overview of how you can set up a server to monitor the activity of your routers using Python and a database:

1. Server Code:

> Use the socket  module in Python to create a TCP server that listens on
> the specified port.

> Implement code to receive data from  connected routers.

> Extract the router serial number and other relevant information from the
> received data.

> Store the data in a database (e.g., MySQL, PostgrSQL) with timestamps
> for each entry.

> Consider using  a library like asynio or threading to handle multiple
> concurrent connections from routers.

> Use a logging framework like logging to track server activity and
> potential errors.

2. Database:

> Choose a database that supports efficient storage and retrieval  of
> time-series data.

> Create a table with columns for router serial number, timestamp, data
> received, and any additional information needed.

> Implement a mechanism(e.g., triggers) to automatically update the
> database when new data arrives.

3. Handling Race Conditions:

> Process data from the queue one at atime to avoid conflicts and ensure
> data integrity.

4. Additional Features:

> Implement a notification system (e.g., email, SMS) to alert customers
> about router inactivity.

> Develop a web interface or API for customers to view their router's
> activity logs and other relevant information.

> Consider using existing Python frameworks like Django or Flask to build
> a more robust and scalable application.

5. Recommended Frameworks:

> asyncio: For asynchronous  programming and handling multiple concurrent
> connections.

> MySQLb or psycopg2: For interacting with MySQL or PostgreSQL databases,
> respectively.

> Flask or Djago: For building a web interface or API.

> logging: For logging server activity and errors.

Next Steps:

> Start by writing a simple Python script to demonstrate basic functionality (e.g., reading data from a socket and printing it to the console).

> Consider using existing libraries and frameworks to accelerate development and improve code quality.

> Test your server thoroughly with  different scenarios and multiple routers to ensure reliable operation.

Tutorials and stuff:

> Python Socket Programming Tutorial: [https://realpython.com/lessons/python->sockets-part-1-overview/](https://realpython.com/lessons/python-%3Esockets-part-1-overview/)

> MySQLdb Documentation: https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/

> Flask Documentation: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/

> Django Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/